# PHP: Alternative to DateTime

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime

I cannot use DateTime because of the version of PHP I am running.  Can anyone suggest a way to get the equivalent value using strToTime or some other date function. I know this is probably an easy question but I am very rusty on dates in php.

i.e. something like

```
$date = strToTime('today');
```

where $date is a date that I can then manipulate by adding hours and so forth along these lines...

```
$start = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$date->modify('+ 60 minutes');
$end = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: You realise that the version of PHP that you're running is several years out-of-date, and that you really should be upgrading it.... the latest version is PHP7, you must be running < 5.2.0

Comment: wrong. I am running 5.329.  Know your php versions!

Comment: `The DateTime class ¶ 


(PHP 5 >= 5.2.0, PHP 7)
` Know your PHP versions.... and even 5.3.29 is over a year out of date now

Comment: DateTime works find on PHP 5.3.29 - as does 'Carbon' so what exactly is the issue: Ok try: `$date = new \DateTime();` before your code: works fine here on PHP 5.3.29. Unlike the accepted answer - this works with your code, Which was correct.  Whatever. Was just a comment ;)

Comment: You are right.  What caused the code to break was the missing \ although slapyo's answer was a good solution and strtotime is apparently benchmarked as faster than DateTime.  However, why does the documentation not mention the \?.   http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php

Comment: Please read about : [Namespaces overview](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php).  All of PHP after 5.3 uses `namespaces`.  Also: [http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php). It is a useful thing - but it is easy to forget the '\' before names to indicate that it is a PHP `thing`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$startTime = strtotime('now');
$endTime = strtotime('+60 minutes', $startTime);

$start = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $startTime);
$end = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $endTime);
```

You can pass a 2nd parameter to `strtotime` that will be the time that is used when the calculation is made. By default it is `time()`.

[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: To be clear does strtotime, change it into a timestamp and then date format it?  As mentioned am rusty on dates in php.

Comment: `strtotime` returns a timestamp. You will need to format it however you'd like after you're done manipulating it.

Comment: Ok. Thx!  That did it.

Answer (score 0):

There are alternatives, that you can get from **github**, just type **php date** in search.

For example, you can use **moment.php** library, which is a clone of moment.js library which is intented to fix problems among different systems, versions etc...

And to perform date calc in moment.php

For example

```
$m = new \Moment\Moment('2012-05-15T12:30:00', 'CET');
echo $m->addMinutes(60)->format(); // 2012-05-08T13:15:00+0200
```